# Trying to loop around a list from with info from a OptionMenu info

Tags: python, list, loops, variables, tkinter

Trying to loop around a list from with info from a OptionMenu infoWhen i try to loop i get a error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\Homework creator\The accuall program.py", line 79, in create_button
    selecting_qs()
  File "C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\Homework creator\The accuall program.py", line 88, in selecting_qs
    if dif == main_list[n][1]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

My list is made up with numbers and letters so im not sure if my option menu has to be a intiger or a string to be able to search for a specific part in my list.
this is the code:

```
def selecting_qs():
    main_list =  main_file_info()
    dif = difficulty.get()
    for n in main_list:
        if dif == main_list[n][1]:
            print(main_list[n][1])



#delating empty strings and /n from list
def rm(list_):
    return [x for x in list_ if x != '\n' and x != ' ']

#main list order:
#Question ID  ,  Difficulty  ,  Topic  ,  Answer ID  ,  Picture ID  ,  Frequency 
def main_file_info():
    main_list=[]
    main_file = open("main_file.txt","r")
    main_file_info=main_file.readlines()
    for line in main_file_info:
        main_list.append(rm(line.split("@")))
    main_file.close()
    return(main_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the item list with **for n in main_list** and use the result as an index in the same list. If the items in your list are a String or a list, you get an error. Try to use the following code:

```
def selecting_qs():
    main_list =  main_file_info()
    dif = difficulty.get()
    resp = []
    for n in main_list:
        if dif == n[1]:
            resp.append(n[1])
    return resp
```

Comment: Thank you so much, is it possible for every object in the list that matches diff to be put in a separate list ?

Comment: Yes. Just create a list inside your function, append the value if is equal dif and finally return the created list.